# IBM worklight deploy to external server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

we are developing an application on IBM WL Enterprise ver 6.2.0.1.

We have four environments which are (Dev/QA/UAT and PROD).
Each Env has its own URL (For example Dev env has " https://mobile-dev.company.com").

When we do the code build, we need to target the env URL by defining the External server path + the context for the app.
Then we do the build which generates the ".adapter/.wlapp" files.

I need to know where does the Env URL get reflected in these files (.adapters/.wlapp)?

If I changed for example (ProjectName-common.wlapp) to .zip and extracted it, where will I find the Env URL value inside it? (Same question for Adapters files)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not.

The .wlapp contains only the metadata of the application and the web resources.
The URL is stored in the generated project.

- For iOS, that would be the worklight.plist file in the Xcode project.
- For Android, the wlclient.properties in the assets folder of the Android project.
- For WP8, it will also be wlclient.properties.

The adapter is unrelated; in its XML file you will see the URL that the request will be directed at.

Comment: Ok, for the adapter, the XML file will contain a domain parameter which will be directed to our Web services, so it is not an Env specific. For the .wlapp, this MUST be Env specific because generating it will lead to generate the native folder for the platform that is related to (iOS...etc) which will be reflected in the worklight.plist. Am I right?